# Set a menu bar applications font using an IBAction

Tags: macos, cocoa, ibaction, nsstatusbar

Might a method exist to set a menu bar applications titles font also font size using an IBAction, (set font also font size for "title")

```
statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];

[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[statusItem setTitle:@"title"];
[statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
```

Comment: this question isn't clear enough for me to answer:  do you want to set the font size of the *menu items* in your status bar app, or the text in some text view that your application displays?

Comment: i edited this initial post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for individual menu items. Have you tried NSMenuItem's [-setAttributedTitle:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000265-BCIJECCA) method? You can create an NSAttributedString to be any font/color/size you wish, then set the attributed title instead of the regular title.

Frankly, though, you'd better have a good reason to do this beyond "I think it'll look cool" since most users will view that as an annoyance. Especially users with eyesight problems. I'd personally move on to a competing app if such a basic part of the UI was heavily and needlessly customized. Use caution here.

Comment: I currently use setAttributedTitle method to set font, also font size, I prefer to have selectable font sizes set as IBActions

Comment: ...then build the UI needed to offer those selections and re-apply the new attributed titles with the new font when the user changes them. Am I not understanding what it is you're looking for?

Comment: Possibly pardon me for being vague with my request.  I have multiple NSNotifications updating this applications title, on the chance I use setAttributedTitle method, on the chance these NSNotifications update this apps title, this apps title returns to system default font